# A proof of $\varphi$ by showing $ZFC+X \vDash \varphi$ and $ZFC+\neg X \vDash \varphi$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose both $X$ and $\neg X$ are consistent with $ZFC$. If you can show each implies a given statement $\varphi$, then do we have a $ZFC$ proof of $\varphi$?

It is not enough just to say either $X$ or $\neg X$ must be true therefore $\varphi$, because neither is  *provable* in $ZFC$.

Do you know of any examples of statements which have "proofs" of the type I have described (and not directly from $ZFC$)?

EDIT: @ChrisEagle has provided an example in Littlewood's Theorem. Is this method merely more convenient in some cases... will there always be a direct ZFC proof without making these extra assumptions?

Comment: ZFC is perfectly capable of "proof by cases", where the cases are "X" and "not X". This is because $[(X \to B) \land (\lnot X \to B) ] \to B$ is a tautology of classical logic, and all such tautologies are incorporated into the deductive system of ZFC.

Comment: You wrote that question a few days ago. I wrote you an answer, but by the time I hit "add answer" you deleted the question.

Comment: @David: Think *before* posting.

Answer (score 6):

ZFC is a theory in classical first-order logic, and like all such theories it is able to prove any statement in its language that corresponds to a propositional tautology. In particular, if $X$ and $\phi$ are statements of ZFC, then ZFC is able to prove the statement
$$
[(X \to \phi) \land (\lnot X \to \phi)] \to \phi
$$
because this is obtained by substituting $X$ and $\phi$ into a propositional tautology
$$
[(A \to B)\land(\lnot A \to B)] \to B.
$$
This tautology corresponds, in a sense, to "proof by cases".

Now, if $ZFC + X \vdash \phi$ then, by the deduction theorem for first-order logic, ZFC is able to prove $X \to \phi$. Similarly, if $ZFC + \lnot X \vdash \phi$ then ZFC is able to prove $\lnot X \to \phi$. If both of those assumptions hold, then by combining the formal proofs, ZFC is able to prove
$$
(X \to \phi) \land (\lnot X \to \phi)
$$
But then, using the tautology above, ZFC proves $\phi$.

Comment: It's worth noting that this proof technique has been used in practice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Excluded_middle has a few examples.

Comment: Oh good, more examples are welcome!

Comment: It may be worth noting that "ZFC is able to prove", while true, may be a little misleading here: we don't need any axioms of ZFC for this. Truth of instances of propositional tautologies is an axiom of classical first order logic, which is sort of meta with respect to ZFC.

Comment: @tomasz: exactly; this was what the "as such" is meant to indicate in the first sentence. I'll rephrase it.

Comment: @David: I no longer remember the details, but I saw a very nice example a number of years ago. The question was whether there is a topological space with a certain collection of properties. That the answer was *yes* was shown by constructing a certain space $X$ from two other spaces $Y$ and $Z$ and showing that under $\mathsf{CH}$ $X$ had the right properties because $Y$ behaved ‘nicely’, while under $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ it had them because $Z$ did. Thus, it had them in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but there was no way to tell exactly ‘why’ it had them without assuming something about the continuum.

Comment: @David: It was a conference talk over $35$ years ago, so I didn’t think that I’d be able to come up with anything, but I got lucky. I remembered that it was by William A.R. Weiss or Murray Bell, and after a bit of digging I found [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183537262) in which Weiss shows that there is a compact Hausdorff space $X$ that is not Blumberg, the result that I heard him present back in the $70$s.